# Use column values of one data and use it to plot in another

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two data table `dat` and `dat.num`. I have made a barplot from data `dat`. In the x-axis I'd like to include the values of column `n` from data `dat.num`. Here I have done it manually but is there a way to directly copy it from the data `dat.num`? Also in the title of the plot I'd like to include the sum of `n`. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
dat <- read.table(text = "Var Type1 Type2
A1 9217    13725
A2 6226    9133
A3 14888   21531
A4 5272    7482
A5 4489    6608
A6 8298    12212", header= T)

dat.num <- read.table(text = "n Dat Mat
                      3 5 8
                      10 2 3
                      11 2 5
                      100 2 5
                      1 2 33
                      15 2 3", header=T)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
dat.m <- melt(dat)

ggplot(dat.m, aes(Var, value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c('A1','A2','A3','A4','A5','A6'),
                   labels= c('name1\n(n=3)',
                             'name2\n(n=10)',
                             'name3\n(n=11)',
                             'name4\n(n=100)',
                             'name5\n(n=1)',
                             'name6\n(n=15)'))+
  labs(x="Type", 
       y="Value",
       title="My plot",
       subtitle="n_total = 140")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `paste()` or `paste0()` to set the x-axis labels & subtitle instead, like so:

```
ggplot(dat.m, aes(Var, value, fill = variable)) + 
 geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
 scale_x_discrete(limits=c('A1','A2','A3','A4','A5','A6'),
                  labels= paste0("name", 1:6, "\n(n=", dat.num$n, ")"))+
 labs(x="Type", 
      y="Value",
      title="My plot",
      subtitle=paste("n_total =",  sum(dat.num$n)))
```

By default, `paste()` uses a space as a separator between strings. `paste0()` is equivalent to `paste(..., sep = "")`, with no separator.

Comment: Use a single `paste0` with your names in a vector instead. Eg. `paste0(c("abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqr"), "\n(n=", dat.num$n, ")")`